# Which A2SD should I use with AOKP VJ 4.2.2 Jelly Bean v2.1 on HTC Desire

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, htc-desire, custom-roms, aokp

I have a rooted HTC Desire with the AOKP VJ 4.2.2 Jelly Bean v2.1 ROM from here:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1863780

I have successfully installed the ROM but am confused as to what solution to use for Apps2SD/A2SD.  I'm a real beginner on that stuff!

I have tried 40ad2sdx-a2 installed as in recovery from a zip file, and also installed through adb push, but the phone won't boot.  Have formatted the SD card with 2 primary partitions (FAT32 14gb and then EXT4 2gb).

Basically, I just want a Jelly Bean ROM with plenty of space for apps..!  Can anyone give me a recommendation of an A2SD method that works and step-by-step instructions how to install?

Comment: This ROM has stock A2SD . Check [comment](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1863780#post30966527)

Comment: Yeah I see that - I just don't understand what "Stock A2SD" is or how to enable it...

Answer (score 1):

Create an ext4 partition with 1Gb space (for example). Then, the first time you enter the ROM, type in terminal emulator:

```
su    
a2sd xdata  
y  
y
```

Now, you have 1Gb internal memory.

Comment: What is y? is that a command?

Comment: probably 'y' is meant as keyboard input for confirmation (when a2sd executes).

Comment: it is mobile specific ? I can use this command to any mobile?

Comment: this answer should be accepted ! it is working fine on my device

Answer (score -1):

I have cm10 4.1.2 on my desire

to get more space I partitioned the sd card (using rom manager I think)

After struggling for some time to get a2sd working with no luck I downloaded mount2sd from google play - this app was great it just seemed to sort everything out with virtually no input from me.

I dont understand it but I assume its a script that analyses the phones memory and then sends commands to a2sd to make it work best with the card - great for someone like me who likes things simple.

Might be worth a try

Martin